# F# Bool list check if 1 element in the list true

Tags: list, f#

I have a list of booleans and I want to check if 1 element in the list is true. The way my program works is whenever a boolean list is created it'll have only one true value or none at all.

Any ideas how I could go about this?

Comment: What are you asking? How check the value of an item at a specific location or how to determine if any item is true?

Comment: also, should the check ensure that there is really only one `true` and no more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.contains%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to see if there is a true value within the list:

```
let containsTrue = theBoolList |> List.contains true
```

If you need to check for *exactly one* true value, you could [`fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B%27t%2C%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) over the list to count them:

```
let fn count item = if item then (count + 1) else count
let numberOfTrue = theBoolList |> List.fold fn 0

let onlyOneTrue = numberOfTrue = 1
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think my logic may be a bit wrong. Could you add a bit of code that does the same but if it finds false, it returns false. i tried changing your code so it was looking for false, but if it found it, it'd return true.

Comment: @JacksonSentzke You want something where it's true if all elements are true, and false if any are false?  Might make sense to do a new question with the requirements, since it's very different than this question... (if you post a link here, I'll reply there)

Comment: @JacksonSentzke Or ask in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f :) We can discuss your requirements easier.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I only realized my mistake after I put your code in my program.

Comment: `let exactlyOneTrue bools = List.filter id bools = [true]`